# Define type parameter constraint for static method inclusion

Tags: typescript, generic-programming

In case of a serializer, can I define type parameter constraints that the type has a specific static member / implements an interface "statically"?

Meaning:

```
function getStuff<T>(...) -> T {
  T.buildFormJson(getStuffJson(...))
}
```

where `buildFromJson` is a `function(input: Object): T`

Can I define a constraint for T to only accept types that have this static member defined?

Comment: So what is your expected argument to `getStuff()` at runtime?  If you have to pass in the class constructor along with other arguments, then maybe the typing is `function getStuff<T>(ctor: {buildFromJson(x: object): T}, stuff: Stuff): T { return ctor.buildFromJson(getStuffJson(stuff));}`.  But without a [mcve] it's hard to tell; consider making an example that can be used by others to demonstrate your issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462#issuecomment-275860898

```
interface JsonDeserializable<T> {
  fromJson(obj: Object): T;
}
interface JsonSerializable {
  toJson(): Object;
}
```

Usage:

```
import * as assert from "assert";

class Point2D {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }


  toJson(): Object {
    return this;
  }

  static fromJson(obj: Object): Point3D {
    return new Point3D(obj['x'], obj['y'], obj['z']);
  }
}

class Point3D {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number, z: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  toJson(): Object {
    return this;
  }

  static fromJson(obj: Object): Point3D {
    return new Point3D(obj['x'], obj['y'], obj['z']);
  }
}


class Baz {
  foo: Point2D;
  bar: Point3D;

  constructor(foo: Point2D, bar: Point3D) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  toJson(): Object {
    return {
      foo: this.foo.toJson(),
      bar: this.bar.toJson()
    }
  }

  static fromJson(obj: Object): Baz {
    return new Baz(Point2D.fromJson(obj['foo']), Point3D.fromJson(obj['bar']));
  }
}



var DATA: Object = {};

function getJson(): Object {
  return DATA;
}

function saveJson(o: Object) {
  DATA = o;
}


// Only accepts T that is serializable
function save<T extends JsonSerializable>(o: T) {
  const json = o.toJson();
  saveJson(json);
}

// Only accepts T that is deserializable
function load<InstanceType>(cls: JsonDeserializable<InstanceType>): InstanceType {
  const data = getJson();

  return cls.fromJson(data);
}

// Only accepts T that is both serializable and deserializable
function testSerde<T extends JsonSerializable>(cls: JsonDeserializable<T>, obj: Object) {
  const instance = cls.fromJson(obj);
  const json = instance.toJson();

  assert.deepEqual(json, obj);
}


const baz = new Baz(new Point2D(1,2), new Point3D(1,2,3));

save(baz);
console.log(load(Baz)); // Baz object
testSerde(Baz, { foo: { x: 1, y: 2 }, bar: {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this might answer your question.  A `class` in JavaScript is just a fancy `function`, and a `static` member of a class is just a property of that function (i.e. it's not a member of the function's `prototype`).

So, we can make `T` extend `Function & { new(...args: any): any } & { buildFormJson(input: object): InstanceType<T> }`.  I've abstracted the first two parts of the intersection into a generic type called `ClassType<S>` where `S` is the interface defining the static members.

```ts
function getStuffJson() {
    return {};
}

type ClassType<S> = Function & { new(...args: any): any } & S;

function getStuff<T extends ClassType<{ buildFormJson(input: object): InstanceType<T> }>>(myClass: T) {
    return myClass.buildFormJson(getStuffJson());
}

class TestClass {
    static buildFormJson(): TestClass {
        return {};
    }
}

getStuff(TestClass);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMpRMYApAZwQAoBKRAbwChFbEAndEepCgXwG4q2qqoBPAA6pEAYQA2AQwIEAKkNQAeDAD5EAXkQAxcNHhIAZJURhUAd2IA6a5PrICALkSSw-Uk5f9EbREYxcqUEhYBBR0LBxgRVlEVAAPKFQwABMCMSkZeWFFCkQAIxAYcWStOHoAW0ISGDBBECgnODyAK1Rod0QASTACKBcIVCylWTU2FRVicv4JaUdEWXJqOgYmFkQpmZlLAqKSssqiMGI0TGxcKqPSUi4eKggMtNlUXs20pbpeyVgIfMLi0oqFzITieLwelBoyzojGwa3YXGWPFuJwiuGIoKgr2uQA)